# What's difference between .in() and all.() operators in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm just curious what's difference between .in() and .all() methods in mongoose Query?
Can you explain by a simple example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is the explanation from mongodb.org:

**$all**

The $all operator is similar to $in, but instead of matching any value in the specified array all values in the array must be matched. For example, the object

{ a: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }

would be matched by

db.things.find( { a: { $all: [ 2, 3 ] } } );

but not

db.things.find( { a: { $all: [ 2, 3, 4 ] } } );

An array can have more elements than those specified by the $all criteria. $all specifies a minimum set of elements that must be matched.

Read more about mongodb operators [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries)

Answer (score 26):

`$all` operator retrieves all the documents which contains the subset of the values we pass. The subset might be in any order.

`$in` operator retrieves all the documents which contains the either of the values we pass.

For example, consider the collection "skills" with following documents:

```
{ "Name" : "Balaji", "skills" : [ "Dancing", "Cooking", "Singing" ] }
{ "Name" : "Ramesh", "skills" : [ "Cooking", "Singing" ] }
{ "Name" : "Suresh", "skills" : [ "Dancing", "Singing" ] }
```

`db.skills.find({skills: { $all : ["Cooking", "Singing" ] } } )` will return only the documents which contains both cooking and singing skills as a set ie Balaji and Ramesh.

`db.skills.find({skills: { $in : ["Cooking", "Singing" ] } } )` will return all the documents since all documents contains either cooking or singing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$all - This an array operator that is equivalent to an $and operation.

[
    {name:'Shubham',hobbies:['cricket','dancing','football']},
    {name:'Chandrakesha',hobbies:['cricket','singing','dancing','football']},
    {name:'Nitish',hobbies:['cricket','singing','dancing','football']},
    {name:'Lovish',hobbies:['readingbooks','singing','dancing','football']},
]

Query:->

{hobbies: { $all : ["readingbooks", "singing" ] } }
                OR
can write like below query
{ 
    $and: [
        {"hobbies": "readingbooks"},
        {"hobbies": "singing"},
    ]
}

will return only the documents which contains both readingbooks and singing hobbies

output:->

[
    {name:'Lovish',hobbies:['readingbooks','singing','dancing','football']},
]

-------------------------------
$in operator retrieves all the documents which contains the either of the values we pass.

[
    {name:'Shubham',hobbies:['cricket','dancing','football']},
    {name:'Chandrakesha',hobbies:['cricket','singing','dancing','football']},
    {name:'Nitish',hobbies:['cricket','singing','dancing','football']},
    {name:'Lovish',hobbies:['readingbooks','singing','dancing','football']},
]

Query:->

{hobbies: { $in : ["readingbooks", "singing" ] } }

                OR
can write like below query
{ 
    $or: [
        {"hobbies": "readingbooks"},
        {"hobbies": "singing"},
    ]
}

will return all the documents which contains any of them readingbooks or singing hobbies

output:->

[
    {name:'Chandrakesha',hobbies:['cricket','singing','dancing','football']},
    {name:'Nitish',hobbies:['cricket','singing','dancing','football']},
    {name:'Lovish',hobbies:['readingbooks','singing','dancing','football']},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following collection 'gamesapp'

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("7892de7a123be821ebcca757"),
   name: "kid1",
   games: [ "Chess", "Cricket", "Football", "Hockey", "Carrom" ],
   favourite_games: [ "Chess", "Cricket", "Football" ]
}

{
   _id: ObjectId("7892de7a123be821ebcca758"),
   name: "kid2",
   games: [ "Chess", "Cricket", "Football", "Hockey", "Carrom" ],
   favourite_games: [ "Chess", "Cricket" ]
}

{
   _id: ObjectId("7892de7a123be821ebcca759"),
   name: "kid3",
   games: [ "Chess", "Cricket", "Football", "Hockey", "Carrom" ],
   favourite_games: [ "Chess" ]
}

{
   _id: ObjectId("7892de7a123be821ebcca760"),
   name: "kid4",
   games: [ "Chess", "Cricket", "Football", "Hockey", "Carrom" ],
   favourite_games: [ "Chess", "Cricket" ]
}
```

$all - This an array operator that is equivalent to an AND operation. This shall return documents from a collection if it **matches ALL VALUES** in the *specified array*. The below helps in determining all the documents that have value 'Chess' 'Cricket' **both**.

> db.gamesapp.find({"favourite_games":{$all:["Chess","Cricket"]}})
>
> This shall list the documents that is of ObjectId
>   7892de7a123be821ebcca757, 7892de7a123be821ebcca758 and 7892de7a123be821ebcca760

$in - This is a comparison query operator which is based on array that lists the possible conditions. It helps in querying a variety of values It lists documents that **matches** **ANY OF THE values** that exist in the *specified array* in the query. The below helps in determining all the documents that have values 'Chess' **or** 'Cricket'

> db.gamesapp.find({"favourite_games":{$in:["Chess", "Cricket"]}})
>
> This shall list all the documents that is of ObjectId
>   7892de7a123be821ebcca757 , 7892de7a123be821ebcca758,
>   7892de7a123be821ebcca759 and 7892de7a123be821ebcca760

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `$size` to check the length of the objects to search excat match opertion.

```
db.getCollection("testCollection").find({
   "status": true,
   "attributes": {
       "$size":6, // Ensure the array has exactly 6 elements
       "$all": [
           { "key": "key0", "value": "1" },
           { "key": "key1", "value": "N" }
       ]
   }
});
```

This will be excat match.