# MongoDB:Querying across a list of items in array field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to implement a bus route listing application. My goal is to list buses that passes through two user given points(locations).

I am using mongodb in the backend. A simple structure of the data is like:

```
....
{ name: 'Bus-N', route: ["Loc1", "Loc2", "Loc3", "Loc4", "Loc5" ], startTime:'..'},
{ name: 'Bus-M', route: ["Loc2", "Loc3", "Loc4"], startTime:'..'}
....
```

**Assumption**: I have the list of all buses and for each bus I have all of it's travel routes.

User gives his `start location` and his `destination` as input.

1. How can I use these inputs(start location and destination) to query across this database to list all the buses passing by the two points? 
   For example: If the input is `(Loc3, Loc4)` I need the output as `(Bus-N, Bus-M)`.
2. If there is a better way to implement this(which obviously there should be), please recommend the required changes.

I am new to `mongodb`. Please help with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: `$all` is what you're looking for: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8145558/6082280). Tested it too..it works. `db.collection.find({ route: { $all: ["Loc3", "Loc4"] } })`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use array query operators like:

1. `$elemMatch`
2. `$and`

during your `.find` or `.findOne` query. You could find more info about it [in the official MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/), (syntax for mongoose is just the same)

You also could find useful information for your case in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027636/whats-difference-between-in-and-all-operators-in-mongoose) which explains the difference between `$all` and `$in` operators for array fields.

Your query should be looked like this:

`Model.find({ route: { $in: ["start_point", "dest_point"] } }).exec(callback)`

Comment: Is there a better solution to this problem? Is this method gong to work well if I have a few thousand entries?

Comment: @Joseph, the only was to improve performance on large-scale collections in using `index` on necessary fields. I am just answering another question on SW about it, so you could check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841749/mongodb-aggregate-query-performance-improvement and other links in that question. I guess you'll find it very helpful in your case, esp if you need to build out huge and complicated queries via `aggregation`. But the only problem that I don't know how much index increases mongo performance on array type fields.